# Publishing maps and services to ArcGIS Server 9.3 when created by ArcGIS Desktop 10.0?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, arcgis-9.3

We have license of  (ArcGIS desktop10) for our users.

We use it for create maps, when we want to publish that maps and services by licensed ArcGIS for server 9.3 , we first  convert MXD  (version 10) to  version (9.3) then publish it, The problem is we miss many things (Resolution of layers[Satellite image, features(line,...],some tools like (pan, identify tool,...) not work as well, and  some data not display!!
(NOTE: we don't have ArcGIS for server10)

My questions are:

1. What should we do to get a maps and services with more accuracy and clarity ?
2. Can we do any thing to  publish maps and services (that created by ArcGIS Desktop10) by ArcGIS for Server 9.3 directly without converting versions?

Comment: ArcGIS 9.3 has been in Retired support status for years now, and 10.0 has been Retired a month. There really isn't anything you can do to make ancient software utilize capabilities of newer (but still *old*) software.  If you want modern GIS capabilities,  you're going to need to use modern software components which are compatible with each other.